# iOS - customize class method in a singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios6

I am customizing my singleton class of `CLLocationManager`.

I have

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *sManager;
```

and

```
static MyLocationManager* sMyLocationManager=nil;

+(instancetype)sharedLocationManager{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sMyLocationManager = [[self alloc] init];

    });
    return sMyLocationManager;

}
```

I could able to write my own methods as

```
-(void)settingUserLocationManager{
    if(nil== sMyLocationManager.sManager){
        sMyLocationManager.sManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
}
-(void)onStartUpdatingUserLocation{
    [sMyLocationManager.sManager startUpdatingLocation];
    return;
}
-(void)onStopUpdatingUserLocation{
    [sMyLocationManager.sManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

`startUpdatingLocation` and `stopUpdatingLocation` are instance methods and this how I use them, while `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]`
is a class method. I have no idea how to use that in my singleton class.

I have tries using it as

```
+(BOOL)locationServicesEnabled {
    return [sMyLocationManager.sManager locationServicesEnabled];
}
```

but not working as expected. Kindly add some ideas.

Comment: Did you try assigning a value to the sManager? i mean did you initialize it in any method?

Comment: Yes. I do that in my view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are wrapping the CLLocationManager using your class, the class method follows the same technique.

Your class will contain a method like,

```
+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled
{
  return [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
+(BOOL)locationServicesEnabled {
    return [[sMyLocationManager sharedLocationManager] locationServicesEnabled];
}
```

Comment: Adding that shows a compile time error - 'No visible @interface for MyLocationManager declares the selector sharedLocationManager'